# How to add Tablix in footer of RDLC report?

Tags: c#, wpf, rdlc, ssrs-tablix, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I am creating report there are 3 parts of reports

1. Header (Company name & Address)
2. Body (With two tablix a. Product Details [which is come from database] b. Total & Tax details [which is also come from database])
3. Footer (With Page Number)

Now, problem is if number of products is increase then footer details goes down.
I was tried with rectangle in body section I put table in rectangle but height of rectangle is also increased when number of products is increase.

So, expected out put is I want to Total & Tax details tablix in footer part.

Is it possible? I was googling most. No one has perfect solution.

I tried with putting Total & Tax details tablix in Footer area RDLC prevent to add or drag tablix.

Please help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If my memory serves, both header and footer for RDLC are static. Especially if you are outputting word format result. For PDF and viewers, you can write variables and custom functions embed to the report to update footer value between pages, but this is not easy task.